# How do I clone the Installation ISO onto a DVD?

Tags: system-installation, dvd

I have created an ISO using Rufus for a dual boot system, where there is already a windows partition present on 50% of the drive. However I cannot figure out how to get my older (asus VU43) laptop to boot from the USB stick -- the problem is that this particular model of laptop has a bios that was never properly updated to handle UEFI USB devices.

Therefore I need to move the whole thing to a bootable DVD. What tool can I use for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading and using "Brasero" from the AppCenter (it's a non-curated app, but works flawlessly from here).

"Image Burner" It's a great util but I think it's only for USB drives.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I found a self contained boot disk utility (maybe on the android x86 web site) that would just launch, then give you a menu option to boot the computer using the usb drive. That worked.  here is one such utility:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/